# Cannot remove a part of text in the description on every single article div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to remove the {AC} which is in every description in the articles divs in the home page.
Every div article has its title, its image thumbnail and some short description. At the beginning of every single description there is the {AC} part that i want to remove. So i tried the jQuery code below but not only removes the {AC} but also every div article has the same description. Which is unwanted. Can you help me out please?

```
var descr = jQuery('.nspText').filter('.tleft').filter('.fleft');

descr.each(function(){

    jQuery(this).html(descr.html().replace('{AC}',''));

});
```

Comment: It will be easier to validate if you include a code snippet that includes a sample of the text you're operating on.

Comment: html or jsfiddle help here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is close, but your `.each()` loop is fetching the HTML of only the first element in the list:

```
jQuery(".nspText.tleft.fleft").each(function() {
  var $element = jQuery(this);
  $element.html($element.html().replace("{AC}", ""));
});
```

You code fetched the HTML from `jQuery(descr)` instead of `jQuery(this)`.

A slightly more streamlined way to do this:

```
jQuery(".nspText.tleft.fleft").html(function(index, oldHtml) {
  return oldHtml.replace("{AC}", "");
});
```

The `.html()` method lets you pass in a function, and it'll pass that function the index of each element in the selected list, plus the old HTML of that element. The return value is used as the replacement HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't include the HTML you are operating on, it's hard to validate this works as you expect, but here's a guess.

```js
var descr = jQuery('.nspText div'
).filter('.fleft');

descr.each(function(){
  var $el = jQuery(this);
  var html = $el.html();
  $el.html(html.replace('{AC}',''));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="nspText">
  <div class="tleft">
    <div class="fleft">This has the "AC" text right here: {AC}</div>
    <div class="fleft">This has the "AC" text right here: {AC}</div>
    <div class="fleft">This has the "AC" text right here: {AC}</div>
    <div class="fright">This has the "AC" text right here, but isn't of class "fleft": {AC}</div>
    <div class="fright">This has the "AC" text right here, but isn't of class "fleft": {AC}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```